# Start position of indexOf search in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the indexOf method to search for a substring in a String variable in Actionscript 3.  The indexOf method allows you to specify a second, optional parameter - the starting position for the search.  However, I'm not sure whether the position returned by indexOf is relative to the very beginning of the string, or to this optional parameter.  Anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to check...

```
trace("ABCDEFG".indexOf("DEF", 3));

// outputs 3
```

It's relative to the string from the start.